# Semicovering and homotopy lifting property

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Has a semicovering map ( local homeomorphism + unique path lifting property ), the homotopy lifting property? Clearly it has the homotopy path lifting property.

Comment: The paper on semicoverings by J. Brazas Homology, Homotopy and Applications, vol. 14(1), 2012, pp.33–63, gives: Deﬁnition 3.1. A semicovering map is a local homeomorphism with continuous lifting of paths and homotopies.. So you need to look carefully at that paper.